# Edit and save profile error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I'm trying to implement a ViewController feature to edit and save Profiles with the help of Firebase but, I get the error: **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** when using this code below:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    var data = Data()
    data = profileImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)!
    DataService.dataService.SaveProfile(username: usernameTextfield.text!, email: emailTextfield.text!, data: data as NSData)
}
```

Comment: don't use `!` if you are not sure that it must have value use this `?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use following ( if let statements ) to check optional value errors.

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    var data = Data()
    if let image = profileImage.image {
        if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            DataService.dataService.SaveProfile(username: usernameTextfield.text!, email: emailTextfield.text!, data: data as NSData)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code solved the error, but the save button don't work

Comment: @potatoonion because you don't have a valid image in the image view.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri um how do I fix that?

Comment: It's your image view. You should store an image there?

Comment: I tried store a image but nothing still happens when I click on the save button, thought it's also the username and email textfields that don't save either when I try to change it. Maybe something is wrong with the button?